# gulp при установке выдает ошибку

Tags: gulp

> fls-start@1.0.0 dev
> gulp && webpack serve --progress -c config/webpack.dev.js

file:///C:/Users/%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8F%D0%BD/Desktop/lesson_20/gulpfile.js:10
import del from 'del';
^^^
SyntaxError: The requested module 'del' does not provide an export named 'default'

кто знает ответ подскажите пожалуйста

Comment: Так прямо в ошибке ваше решение, попробуйте [перевести её](https://lingva.ml/).

Comment: Переводил но дело в том что я начинающий и ответ не дал мне не чего-устанавливаю по видео  уроку

Comment: там все норм а у меня вылезла ошибка  как исправить не знаю

Comment: Судя по ошибке, при экспорте не используется спец слово `default`, пример: `export default function hello() { /* do something */ }`

Comment: КАК Я ПРОБОВАЛ РАЗОБРАТЬСЯ ЧТО-ТО С ПАПКОЙ DEV ОН НЕ МОЖЕТ ЕЕ ВЫЗВАТЬ САМОМУ НЕ РЕАЛЬНО РАЗОБРАТЬСЯ

Comment: попробуйте установить del версии 6

Answer (score 0):

я тоже столкнулся с такой проблемой, удалось решить проблему ?
У меня такая же фигня,старый проект запускаю все норм новый запускаю точь в точь как у тебя. Ps. Удалось решить через npm install del@6

Comment: В текущем виде ваш ответ непонятен. Пожалуйста, нажмите [edit] под сообщением, чтобы добавить больше подробностей, которые помогут другим понять, как он отвечает на заданный вопрос. Вы можете найти больше информации о том, как писать хорошие ответы в [Справке](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: при установке выдает другую ошибку - буду дальше разбираться но твой метод помог СП большое