# The requested module 'del' does not provide an export named 'default'

Tags: javascript, node.js, webpack, gulp

[image: введите сюда описание изображения][image: введите сюда описание изображения]Пытаюсь запустить сборку. Ничего с ней не делал, прошлый проект нормально запускался. Но запускаю новый - появляется эта ошибка. Пробовал менять `constant` (сonst) в функции на `default` - ничего не меняется.
Пробовал изменять первую строку на `import * as del from "del"` - также ничего не происходит. Проверил этот же файл в прошлом проекте, всё идентично написано.

Помогите, пожалуйста.[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: `import {del} from 'del'` - пробовали?

Comment: Здравствуйте! Пробовал. Ничего...

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [gulp при установке выдает ошибку](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1432522/gulp-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b8-%d1%83%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%ba%d0%b5-%d0%b2%d1%8b%d0%b4%d0%b0%d0%b5%d1%82-%d0%be%d1%88%d0%b8%d0%b1%d0%ba%d1%83)

Comment: Покажите что лежит в `del`

Comment: Добавил в качестве изменения вопроса

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/search?q=The+requested+module+%27del%27+does+not+provide+an+export+named+%27default%27

Comment: Ещё не пробовал устанавливать del версии 6. Подскажите, пожалуйста, как это сделать?

Comment: Да не просто папку `del`, а что лежит в файле `index.js`, который в нём. Но вроде вам надо что-то другое сделать, чтобы проблему решить

Comment: `npm install del@6`

Comment: После установки `del` 6 версии появляется другая проблема. Добавил фото в изменении.

Comment: оу, я не заметил, что у вас ESM синтаксис. верните 7 и попробуйте что-то вроде `import * as del from 'del'`

Comment: Вернуть старую версию del? Если это так, то я уже пробовал `import * as del from 'del'`. Ничего не меняется ( в описании вопроса)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
import {deleteAsync}  from "del";

export const reset = () => {
    return deleteAsync(app.path.clean);
}
```

Comment: Спасибо за помощь! Но я использую ESM синтаксис, следовательно, такого модуля нет.

Answer (score 1):

Мне помогла замена в файле package.json с:

```
"del":"latest"
```

на

```
"del":"^6.1.1"
```

Answer (score 1):

Все же используй лучше

```
import { deleteAsync } from "del";
export const reset = () => {
    return deleteAsync(app.path.clean);
};
```

Сам долго разбирался и это должно помочь!

Answer (score 0):

удалось решить проблему ?
У меня такая же фигня,старый проект запускаю все норм новый запускаю точь в точь как у тебя.
Ps. Удалось решить через npm install del@6

Comment: В текущем виде ваш ответ непонятен. Пожалуйста, нажмите [edit] под сообщением, чтобы добавить больше подробностей, которые помогут другим понять, как он отвечает на заданный вопрос. Вы можете найти больше информации о том, как писать хорошие ответы в [Справке](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Бесполезно. Выскакивает другая проблема - последний скрин

Comment: В общем, это какой-то парадокс. Откатил до 6 версии и всё заработало, хотя раньше это не помогло. Спасибо!

Answer (score 0):

Сам способ подключения изменился. 
На сайте [npmjs – del](https://www.npmjs.com/package/del) можно прочитать как использовать.

Содержимое файла gulpfile.js я подключил вот так, это работает для меня. 
`import { deleteAsync } from 'del';` // Удалить файлы и каталоги. 
`function clear() { return deleteAsync(build) }`// Очищаем папку build перед каждым запуском сборки.

================ 
Сейчас старый метод у меня перестал работать, теперь работает вот так вот:

`import del from 'del'; // Удалить файлы и каталоги.`

```
// Очищаем папку build перед каждым запуском сборки.
async function clear() {
  await del(build);
}
```